# Running chrome driver with python flask on heroku (pyppeteer)

Tags: python, google-chrome, flask, heroku, chromium

I am using pyppeteer in my flask app. I am hosting on heroku but when the browser opens it closes back.

Heroku log:

2021-06-18T16:45:52.764390+00:00 app[web.1]: raise BrowserError('Browser closed unexpectedly:\n')
2021-06-18T16:45:52.764509+00:00 app[web.1]: pyppeteer.errors.BrowserError: Browser closed unexpectedly:

I did some research and some people said to add a buildpack so i did heroku buildpacks:add heroku/google-chrome to add the buildpack.

But the same thing is still happening.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I changed the launch statement to this browser = await launch(handleSIGINT=False, handleSIGTERM=False, handleSIGHUP=False, options={'args': ['--no-sandbox']}) and it works :)